# Proper sizing of images used for full-width backgrounds

Tags: css, html, background

I'm looking for some clarification on how wide to make images used as section of a page's background.  For example, in a variable-width design with a fixed size content section, it's common to have a background image attached to the body of a page and then additional images that will span the full browser width that are set as (centered) background images on additional divs.

I understand for the most part how this works, but I'm looking for guidance on just how wide to make the images.  I've seen sites using 4000 pixel wide backgrounds, even 8000 pixel wide backgrounds, which is wider than any user's browser window is ever likely to be.

Is this technique relying on some underlying quirk, and is that what drives the massive width?

I'm also curious as to the logic behind why a backgound image for a div is able to fall outside of the rest of the flow of elements on a page.  Again, I know it works, but I'm curious as to why.

Answer (score 1):

When using a large photo as a background image, I wouldn't go bigger than 2560x1440px, which is the resolution on a 27" iMac screen: http://support.apple.com/kb/sp623. 1366x768px is the most common monitor resolution, followed by 1920x1080px: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_resolution_higher.asp.

If you have a fixed width section of content and you want an image to fill that section, make the image the size of the section and use css to scale it: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/. I am assuming that you're using a photo for a background image and not a repeating pattern. In that case you just scale the image to the size of the pattern before it repeats.

Comment: So is it generally safe to assume that there's no practical purpose to those gigantic 4000+ pixel images I've seen?  Also just to clarify, the second part of my question is not about an image inside a div necessarily, but even the background on the page - specifically, if it's centered and much wider than the browser window, why does the expanded body width due to the background not throw all descendant positioning way off?